# Retrofit 2 @Get method returning blank results

Tags: android, retrofit2

i have an api link i want to pass parameters to using the get retrofit method. the link is

```
/ambulance/location?latitude=-1.6078289&longitude=38.779225&limit=10
```

I have the Retrofit 2 class below:

```
@GET("/ambulance/location")
Call<AmbulanceModel> getNearbyAmbulances(@Query("latitude") String   latitude,
                                         @Query("longitude") String longitude,
                                         @Query("limit") int limit);
```

and in my main activity, i have the code below;

```
Call<AmbulanceModel> call = api.getNearbyAmbulances(latitude + " ", longitude + " " , LIMIT);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<AmbulanceModel>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<AmbulanceModel> call, Response<AmbulanceModel> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                ambulanceList = (ArrayList<AmbulanceList>) response.body().getData();
                for (int i = 0; i < ambulanceList.size(); i++) {
                    AmbulanceList ambulance = ambulanceList.get(i);
                    mAmbulanceAdapter.addAmbulance(ambulance);
                }
            }
```

The problem is, I'm getting a blank/empty page (no results). Im thinking Retrofit is not sending the parameters to my server api. I have checked the logcat for errors but there're none kindly help.

Is this the right way to pass parameters to the api on the retrofit get method?

Model classes Object model

```
public class AmbulanceModel implements Serializable {

private Integer success;
private String message;
private Object error;
private List<AmbulanceList> data = new ArrayList<AmbulanceList>(); //array
private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

/**
 *
 * @return
 * The success
 */
public Integer getSuccess() {
    return success;
}

/**
 *
 * @param success
 * The success
 */
public void setSuccess(Integer success) {
    this.success = success;
}

/**
 *
 * @return
 * The message
 */
public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

/**
 *
 * @param message
 * The message
 */
public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}

/**
 *
 * @return
 * The error
 */
public Object getError() {
    return error;
}

/**
 *
 * @param error
 * The error
 */
public void setError(Object error) {
    this.error = error;
}

/**
 *
 * @return
 * The data
 */
public List<AmbulanceList> getData() {
    return data;
}

/**
 *
 * @param data
 * The data
 */
public void setData(List<AmbulanceList> data) {
    this.data = data;
}

public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
    return this.additionalProperties;
}

public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
    this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
}
```

}

Array model

```
public class AmbulanceList implements Serializable {

private Integer id;
private String name;
private String locationName;
private String latitude;
private String longitude;
private String dateAdded;
private String distance;
private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

/**
 *
 * @return
 * The id
 */
public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

/**
 *
 * @param id
 * The id
 */
public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

/**
 *
 * @return
 * The name
 */
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

/**
 *
 * @param name
 * The name
 */
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

/**
 *
 * @return
 * The locationName
 */
public String getLocationName() {
    return locationName;
}

/**
 *
 * @param locationName
 * The location_name
 */
public void setLocationName(String locationName) {
    this.locationName = locationName;
}

/**
 *
 * @return
 * The latitude
 */
public String getLatitude() {
    return latitude;
}

/**
 *
 * @param latitude
 * The latitude
 */
public void setLatitude(String latitude) {
    this.latitude = latitude;
}

/**
 *
 * @return
 * The longitude
 */
public String getLongitude() {
    return longitude;
}

/**
 *
 * @param longitude
 * The longitude
 */
public void setLongitude(String longitude) {
    this.longitude = longitude;
}

/**
 *
 * @return
 * The dateAdded
 */
public String getDateAdded() {
    return dateAdded;
}

/**
 *
 * @param dateAdded
 * The date_added
 */
public void setDateAdded(String dateAdded) {
    this.dateAdded = dateAdded;
}

/**
 *
 * @return
 * The distance
 */
public String getDistance() {
    return distance;
}

/**
 *
 * @param distance
 * The distance
 */
public void setDistance(String distance) {
    this.distance = distance;
}

public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
    return this.additionalProperties;
}

public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
    this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
}
```

}

The json

```
{
"success": 1,
"message": "Success",
"error": null,
"data": [
   {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "St John Ambulance Kenya",
    "location_name": "Nairobi",
    "latitude": "-1.2913421",
    "longitude": "36.8208557",
    "date_added": "2016-09-26T00:45:38Z",
    "distance": 10.378971445601792
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "AMREF Flying Doctors",
    "location_name": "Wilson Airport",
    "latitude": "-1.318542",
    "longitude": "36.7445514",
    "date_added": "2016-09-26T00:49:11Z",
    "distance": 12.884862762969318
   },
```

Comment: Add some `Log` statments into the Retrofit call to see what is returned

Comment: why do you think you have to cast the data `(ArrayList<AmbulanceList>)`?

Comment: also, show the content of the json you expect to receive.

Comment: You seem to think you are returning a list, so make the interface as `Call<List<AmbulanceModel>>`

Comment: @njzk2 I'm displaying the data on a recyclerView via an adapter

Comment: @cricket_007 let me try it

Comment: @njzk2 here you go  "data": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "St John Ambulance Kenya",
      "location_name": "Nairobi",
      "latitude": "-1.2913421",
      "longitude": "36.8208557",
      "date_added": "2016-09-26T00:45:38Z",
      "distance": 10.378971445601792
    }

Comment: There is a misunderstanding toward what your returned model should be. What are `AmbulanceList` and `AmbulanceModel`?

Comment: @njzk2 'AmbulanceModel' is the structure of the json that contains the 'data object' the 'AmbulanceList' is the array within the 'data object'

Comment: I suggest you take a look at the return type of `response.body().getData();`. You probably want to do something like `ambulanceList = response.body().getData().getAmbulanceList();` Also, since you receive nothing, there is probably an issue with your model. Post your model classes too.

Comment: `latitude + " "` this is probably wrong. depending on your server, this can really mess things up because you add an extra space. Either use `String.valueOf`, or declare your parameters as floats directly.

Comment: @njzk2 adding getAmbulanceList(); throws an error because that method is not in my model classes. the getData(); method pulls the data object contents from AmbulanceMode. comments have a limited number of words unfortunately.

Comment: oh, I see. `getData` is a method of `AmbulanceModel`. But then why do you need to cast? Edit your question and add the models.

Comment: @njzk2 removed the spaces. no difference. ill try String.valueOf

Comment: Ive edited it and added more data as well as the json @njzk2

Comment: did you put a breakpoint in the callback to see what happens exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Check if your base URL (used when creating the Retrofit instance) ends with a "/". Also remove the first "/" in your @GET annotation :

```
@GET("ambulance/location")
```

Comment: it doesnt have. i checked as first thing